# How to fix the Integer literal '2147483648' overflows when stored into 'Int' exception?

Tags: swift, byte

```
let stringData = "84121516"  // this is 4 bytes data
let value = self.checkHexToInt(stringData: stringData)
 func checkHexToInt(stringData: String) -> Int? {
    guard let num = Int(stringData, radix: 16) else {
      return nil
    }
    return Int(num)
  }


// values is 2215777558 But I need most significant bit only

let checkEngineLightOn = ((value! & 0x80000000) > 0);
```

When I am doing this I got the exception saying "Integer literal '2147483648' overflows when stored into 'Int'"

When I do this I am expecting to get either true or false. Or is any other to get most significant bit out of Int Value?

Comment: In 64-bit platforms `Int` represents 64-bit signed integer. And in 32-bit platforms, it's 32-bit **signed** integer. While you know it's a 4 byte data and want to use values greater than `Int32.max`. Why don't you use unsigned 32-bit integer `UInt32`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @OOPer noted in the comments, on a 32-bit system `Int` is 32-bits and your value is larger than `Int32.max`.  Since you are decoding 4 bytes you can use `UInt32`:

```
func checkHexToUInt32(stringData: String) -> UInt32? {
    return UInt32(stringData, radix: 16)
}

let stringData = "84121516"  // this is 4 bytes data
let value = self.checkHexToUInt32(stringData: stringData)
let checkEngineLightOn = ((value! & 0x80000000) > 0)
```

Note:  `UInt32(_:radix:)` returns an `UInt32?` which is `nil` if the conversion fails, so there is no reason for the `guard` and `return nil`, just return the value of the conversion.